# json unmarshal embedded struct

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

I would like to unmarshal to struct `Outer` defined as:

```
type Outer struct {
    Inner
    Num int
}

type Inner struct {
    Data string
}
func (i *Inner) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    i.Data = string(data)
    return nil
}
```

Using `json.Unmarshal(data, &Outer{})` seems only to use `Inner`'s `UnmarshalJSON` and ignores the `Num` field: https://play.golang.org/p/WUBfzpheMl

I have an unwieldy [solution](https://play.golang.org/p/mHs0INz9rV) where I set the `Num` field manually, but I was wondering if anybody had a cleaner or simpler way to do it.

Thanks!

Comment: Note that the reason is explained in this part of the Go language reference: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types (look for word "promoted")

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52305457/7075416) answer explains this interesting interaction better and more completely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because `Inner` is being embedded in `Outer`. That means when json library calls unmarshaler on `Outer`, it instead ends up calling it on `Inner`.

Therefore, inside `func (i *Inner) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte)`, the `data` argument contains the entire json string, which you are then processing for `Inner` only.

You can fix this by making `Inner` explicit field in `Outer`

```
Outer struct {
    I Inner // make Inner an explicit field
    Num int `json:"Num"`
}
```

[Working example](https://play.golang.org/p/TZg70ZrvHp)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Sure, this solves the problem of not unmarshaling `Num`, however, it doesn't work with embedded data such as `{"data": "test", "num": 1}`, it would only work with something like `{"inner": {"data": "test"}, "num": 1}`.

Comment: Agreed with Eric. I think this answer is only barely applicable in this case but in general case it's misleading.

Comment: This is a misleading answer. I understand that the question itself is a bit unclear, but the proposed solution has nothing to do with embedded type.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is to forgo the custom `UnmarshalJSON` function entirely and just use the basic JSON notation, i.e.:

```golang
type Outer struct {
    Inner
    Num int `json:"num"`
}

type Inner struct {
   Data string `json:"data"`
}
```

You lose some of the more granular capabilities you could have with a custom unmarshalling method, but when you're unmarshalling a struct with mostly primitive fields like strings, you really don't need to worry about that.

[Example in go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/KNKkH5qhUNy)

If you really need custom unmarshalling, you could use composition, and give the struct a custom json encoding tag and have the struct contain the fields you want to play with. So if `data` is something that will contain multiple complex fields, you could just change `Inner` to reflect those fields, like this:

```golang
type Outer struct {
    Data Inner `json:"data"`
    Num int `json:"num"`
}

type Inner struct {
    Thing string `json:"thing"`
    OtherThing int `json:"otherThing"`
}
```

[Example in go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/6pFTj8hVezw)

Once again, this doesn't have a custom unmarshalling function, but that can be scraped together for `Inner` easily enough. (Personally, I'd forgo the use of custom unmarshal functions entirely in any given case and just use encoding tags unless I absolutely had to use the unmarshalling function.)

Comment: This works perfectly

Answer (score 2):

Faced same issue. One solution is to unmarshal twice for each sub structs. E.g.

```
type Inner struct {
        Data string
}

type NumField struct {
        Num int
}

type Outer struct {
        Inner
        NumField
}

func (i *Inner) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
        i.Data = string(data)
        return nil
}

func (o *Outer) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
        if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &o.Inner); err != nil {
                return err
        }
        if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &o.NumField); err != nil {
                return err
        }
        return nil
}

func main() {
        x := Outer{}
        data := []byte(`{"Num": 4}`)
        _ = json.Unmarshal(data, &x)
        fmt.Printf("%#v\n", x)
}
```

This requires moving the extra fields into a separate struct.

Comment: Same idea. Explained better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52305457

Answer (score 1):

Just delete `UnmarshalJSON` in your example because it's used in unmarshaling of `Outer` since `Inner` is inlined. Otherwise, you need to override it if you want to do something custom.

https://play.golang.org/p/D6V6vKpx9J

Answer (score -1):

Actually you not need explicit field, you need properly Marshal/UnMarshal

Example: https://play.golang.org/p/mWPM7m44wfK

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Outer struct {
    Inner
    Num int `json:"Num"`
}

type Inner struct{ Data string }

type InnerRaw struct {Data string}

func (i *Inner) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    ir:=&InnerRaw{}
    json.Unmarshal(data, ir)
    i.Data = ir.Data
    return nil
}

func main() {
    x := Outer{}
    data := []byte(`{"Num": 4, "Data":"234"}`)
    _ = json.Unmarshal(data, &x)
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", x)
    js, _:=json.Marshal(x)
    fmt.Printf("JSON:%s", string(js))
}
```

Comment: But `Num` is still 0, even though it should be 4

Comment: Hmm, yes we can remove InnerRaw struct and UnmarshallJSON function. 
Result: https://play.golang.org/p/JkKCLQOnsHp and it works fine

Comment: The OP wants to parse `Num` when there is `UnmarshalJSON` for Inner. If we remove `UnmarshalJSON`, then it wouldn't answer the question