# GoLang structure doesn't unmarshal properly when using a custom unmarshal for a nested struct

Tags: json, go, struct, nested, unmarshalling

We need to use a custom unmarshaler for a struct nested in multiple other structs which don't require a custom unmarshaler. We have lots of structs similar to `B` struct defined below (similar as in nesting `A`). The code's output is `true false 0` (expected `true false 2`). Any ideas?

---

Go Playground example [here](https://play.golang.org/p/JYBLR5klMnO).

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

type A struct {
    X bool `json:"x"`
    Y bool `json:"y"`
}

type B struct {
    A
    Z int `json:"z"`
}

func (a *A) UnmarshalJSON(bytes []byte) error {
    var aa struct {
        X string `json:"x"`
        Y string `json:"y"`
    }
    json.Unmarshal(bytes, &aa)

    a.X = aa.X == "123"
    a.Y = aa.Y == "abc"
    return nil
}

const myJSON = `{"x": "123", "y": "fff", "z": 2}`

func main() {
    var b B
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(myJSON), &b)
    fmt.Print(b.X," ",b.Y," ",b.Z)
}
```

---

EDIT: question was marked as duplicate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38982445/json-unmarshal-embedded-struct) but making `A` an explicit field will make our API cluttered. Also after making `A` an explicit field the result is `false false 2` so it does not help at all.

Comment: Why do you have bools in `A` but strings in the JSON? If you had matching types, then you wouldn't need to write an unmarshaller at all. Perhaps you can have a method for `A` that returns the boolean value based on the string values that it already has?

Comment: @svsd this is just a sample, we receive a string from our front-end but we need a struct that we identify by that string on back-end. Unfortunately, matching types is not an option here.

Comment: (1) Make B embed another struct C which contains the fields not contained in A (2) Write an UnmarshalJSON() method for B which unmarshals the same JSON into both B.A and B.C. See https://play.golang.org/p/roF6hKZJ8Bc

The advantage of defining another type C with the fields not in A is that you can delegate unmarshalling it to the `json` package. (assuming that you have contraints preventing you from matching the types in A and the JSON)

Comment: Just added an answer based on the comment since the question is no longer marked as a duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `B` embeds `A`, `A.UnmarshalJSON()` is exposed as `B.UnmarshalJSON()`. Due to that, `B` implements `json.Unmarshaler` and as a result `json.Unmarshal()` calls `B.UnmarshalJSON()` which only unmarshal's `A`'s fields. That's the reason `B.Z` does not get set from the JSON.

This is the easiest way I could think of to get it working in accordance with your constraint of not changing the data types in `A`:

1. Make B embed another struct C which contains the fields not contained in A.
2. Write an UnmarshalJSON() method for B which unmarshals the same JSON into both B.A and B.C. The advantage of defining another type C with the fields not in A is that you can delegate unmarshalling it to the json package.

With the new `B.UnmarshalJSON()` method, you now have full control to unmarshal the fields outside of `A` as well.

```
type A struct {
    X bool `json:"x"`
    Y bool `json:"y"`
}

func (a *A) UnmarshalJSON(bytes []byte) error {
    // the special unmarshalling logic here
}

type C struct {
    Z int `json:"z"`
}

type B struct {
    A
    C
}

func (b *B) UnmarshalJSON(bytes []byte) error {
    if err := json.Unmarshal(bytes, &b.A); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if err := json.Unmarshal(bytes, &b.C); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```