# Empty result when unmarshalling XML into struct

Tags: xml, go, soap

This is my XML request body:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ads="http://www.lunalovegood.com/sudarsan/">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <ads:Candy>
         <ads:toffee>a3f27f3a0a684700e9ab834df492505d806b1944</ads:toffee>
      </ads:Candy>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

This is my struct definition:

```
type CandyMan struct {
    SOAPEnvelope
    Body struct {
        Candy `xml:"Candy"`
    } `xml:"Body"`
}

type Candy struct {
    Toffee string `xml:"toffee"`
}

type SOAPEnvelope struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"Envelope"`
    Text    string   `xml:",chardata"`
    XSI     string   `xml:"xmlns:xsi,attr"`
    XSD     string   `xml:"xmlns:xsd,attr"`
    Soap    string   `xml:"xmlns:soap,attr"`
}
```

I am trying to unmarshal the XML into the struct:

```
req := dtos.CandyMan{}
err := xml.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&req)
fmt.Println(req, err)
```

I am not getting any error but the unmarshal isn't working. I am getting an empty struct, please help me figure out the issue.
Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38982445/json-unmarshal-embedded-struct may be relevant to you. Although it's a different package, I assume a lot of the unmarshalling logic is the same.

Comment: Don't embed the candy.

Comment: And I'm not sure what you're trying to unmarshal into the `Text` field with `,chardata` but you'll get only *chardata* which is data inside that element but outside of its child elemnts, i.e. you get all the whitespace around Envelope's children.

Comment: If you want to keep the candy embedded you can use `>` to tell the decoder where to find the data for the `Toffee` field, i.e. `Toffee string \`xml:"Candy>toffee"\``. If you don't embed the candy you don't need to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have embedded the `Candy` struct into `Body` struct.

You probably don't want to do that, but rather have something like this:

```golang
type CandyMan struct {
    SOAPEnvelope
    Body struct {
        Candy Candy `xml:"Candy"`
    } `xml:"Body"`
}
```

It seems to be working fine then: https://play.golang.org/p/ilFsLriOAuP